# Postgis UPDATE hangs forever

Tags: django, postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I'm using Django and Postgis for a web app. In my testing env I ran a South schema migration to add `denorm_locs = MultiPointField(null=True)` to a model (adds a new column to the DB table), and then a datamigration to populate the new field. Here's the datamigration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from south.utils import datetime_utils as datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPoint

import time

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        # Note: Don't use "from appname.models import ModelName". 
        # Use orm.ModelName to refer to models in this application,
        # and orm['appname.ModelName'] for models in other applications.

        i = 0
        batch_size = 10

        start = time.time()
        print 'Start: %s' % start

        cont = True

        while cont:
            id_list = orm.MyModel.objects.filter(denorm_locs__isnull=True).order_by('id').values_list('id', flat=True)[:batch_size]

            id_list = list(id_list)

            print 'Got id_list (%s ids): %s' % (len(id_list), time.time() - start,)

            if len(id_list) < batch_size:
                cont = False

            for mymodel_id in id_list:
                locs = [
                    l.loc
                    for l in orm.Location.objects.filter(mymodel3__mymodels__id=mymodel_id)
                    if l.loc
                ]

                mp = MultiPoint(locs)

                orm.MyModel.objects.filter(id=mymodel_id).update(denorm_locs=mp)

            i += 1
            print '%s batches of %s completed' % (i, batch_size,)
```

The Location model just has a PointField called `loc` on it.

When `orm.MyModel.objects.filter(id=mymodel_id).update(denorm_locs=mp)`runs it uses the following query:

`UPDATE "core_mymodel" SET "denorm_locs" = ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x0104000020e610000001000000010100000086c954c1a81054c01d5a643bdfbf3940'::bytea) WHERE "core_mymodel"."id" = 123`

I've had a few iterations complete, but very quickly the for loop encounters a row that hangs forever when trying to UPDATE. As a test I changed the migration to UPDATE a different column, and when the for loop encountered the same row it hung for about 30 seconds before moving on, but it did complete, whereas when trying to update denorm_locs it won't complete at all.

Here's the output of `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;`:

```
 datid | datname  | pid  | usesysid | usename  | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | waiting | state  |                                                                                  query                                                                                   
-------+----------+------+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 16384 | rdsadmin | 1668 |       10 | rdsadmin |                  |             |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |         |        | <insufficient privilege>
 16388 | mydb     | 3658 |    16386 | mydb     |                  | 10.1.250.12 | 10.1.250.12     |       33658 | 2014-07-17 14:57:09.592821+00 | 2014-07-17 15:06:14.208525+00 | 2014-07-17 15:06:14.208525+00 | 2014-07-17 15:06:14.20853+00  | f       | active | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
 16388 | mydb     | 2241 |    16386 | mydb     |                  | 10.1.0.7    | 10.1.0.7        |       51805 | 2014-07-16 20:25:13.621986+00 | 2014-07-16 20:25:14.474963+00 | 2014-07-16 20:25:15.040656+00 | 2014-07-16 20:25:15.040661+00 | f       | active | UPDATE "core_mymodel" SET "denorm_locs" = ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x0104000020e61000000100000001010000009b1da9bef36c54c0815ce2c803b93c40'::bytea) WHERE "core_mymodel"."id" = 1000 
 16388 | mydb     | 2744 |    16386 | mydb     |                  | 10.1.250.12 | 10.1.250.12     |       33554 | 2014-07-17 14:42:09.569238+00 | 2014-07-17 14:50:58.94293+00  | 2014-07-17 14:50:58.960509+00 | 2014-07-17 14:50:58.960512+00 | t       | active | UPDATE "core_mymodel" SET "denorm_locs" = ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x0104000020e610000001000000010100000086c954c1a81054c01d5a643bdfbf3940'::bytea) WHERE "core_mymodel"."id" = 123 
(4 rows)
```

You can still see another query from last night that never completed.

Here's `SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT granted;`:

```
 relation |   locktype    | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid  |   mode    | granted | fastpath 
----------+---------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+------+-----------+---------+----------
          | transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |      14771737 |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | ShareLock | f       | f
(1 row)
```

Here's `SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE granted;`:

```
                          relation                          |   locktype    | database | relation | page  | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid  |       mode       | granted | fastpath 
------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+------+------------------+---------+----------
 pg_locks                                                   | relation      |    16388 |    11090 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/39008            | 3658 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
                                                            | virtualxid    |          |          |       |       | 3/39008    |               |         |       |          | 3/39008            | 3658 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s                                          | relation      |    16388 |    19314 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel3                                                 | relation      |    16388 |    19386 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_location                                              | relation      |    16388 |    19243 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_denorm_locs_id                                  | relation      |    16388 |  2725185 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_title_index                                     | relation      |    16388 |  2700114 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_detail_html_index                               | relation      |    16388 |  2700113 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 title                                                      | relation      |    16388 |  2645243 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id_6dce956e264c19df_uniq | relation      |    16388 |  2576203 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodels_query                                    | relation      |    16388 |  2484701 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel2_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   333698 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel4_id                         | relation      |    16388 |   302491 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id                       | relation      |    16388 |   302490 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_start_date                                      | relation      |    16388 |   302487 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_end_date                                        | relation      |    16388 |   302483 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_pkey                                            | relation      |    16388 |   302308 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel                                                 | relation      |    16388 |    19293 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
                                                            | virtualxid    |          |          |       |       | 4/44       |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s                                          | relation      |    16388 |    19314 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel3                                                 | relation      |    16388 |    19386 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_location                                              | relation      |    16388 |    19243 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_denorm_locs_id                                  | relation      |    16388 |  2725185 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_title_index                                     | relation      |    16388 |  2700114 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_detail_html_index                               | relation      |    16388 |  2700113 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 title                                                      | relation      |    16388 |  2645243 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id_6dce956e264c19df_uniq | relation      |    16388 |  2576203 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodels_query                                    | relation      |    16388 |  2484701 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel2_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   333698 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel4_id                         | relation      |    16388 |   302491 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id                       | relation      |    16388 |   302490 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_start_date                                      | relation      |    16388 |   302487 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_end_date                                        | relation      |    16388 |   302483 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel_pkey                                            | relation      |    16388 |   302308 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 core_mymodel                                                 | relation      |    16388 |    19293 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
                                                            | virtualxid    |          |          |       |       | 5/11758    |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 core_mymodel_mymodel4_id                         | relation      |    16388 |   302491 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_pkey                                     | relation      |    16388 |   302312 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_mymodel_id_5dcd946e263a391f_uniq           | relation      |    16388 |   302310 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_start_date                                      | relation      |    16388 |   302487 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
                                                            | transactionid |          |          |       |       |            |      14771737 |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 core_location_loc_id                                       | relation      |    16388 |   302470 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_pkey                                            | relation      |    16388 |   302361 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_end_date                                        | relation      |    16388 |   302483 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_pkey                                            | relation      |    16388 |   302308 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_name                                            | relation      |    16388 |   333705 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_denorm_locs_id                                  | relation      |    16388 |  2725185 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_title_index                                     | relation      |    16388 |  2700114 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_name_129459df841fd9de_uniq                      | relation      |    16388 |   333668 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel                                                 | tuple         |    16388 |    19293 | 93104 |     3 |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_location_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   302517 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_name_index                                      | relation      |    16388 |  2700014 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id                       | relation      |    16388 |   302490 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel2_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   333698 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id_6dce956e264c19df_uniq | relation      |    16388 |  2576203 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_mymodel_id                                 | relation      |    16388 |   302488 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_address_id                                      | relation      |    16388 |   302516 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_mymodel2_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   333704 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel                                                 | relation      |    16388 |    19293 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_location_pkey                                         | relation      |    16388 |   302276 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_mymodel3_id                                 | relation      |    16388 |   302489 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 title                                                      | relation      |    16388 |  2645243 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_detail_html_index                               | relation      |    16388 |  2700113 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodels_query                                    | relation      |    16388 |  2484701 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_location_pkey                                         | relation      |    16388 |   302276 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_mymodel3_id                                 | relation      |    16388 |   302489 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 title                                                      | relation      |    16388 |  2645243 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_detail_html_index                               | relation      |    16388 |  2700113 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodels_query                                    | relation      |    16388 |  2484701 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_mymodel_id                                 | relation      |    16388 |   302488 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_address_id                                      | relation      |    16388 |   302516 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_mymodel2_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   333704 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel                                                 | relation      |    16388 |    19293 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_name_index                                      | relation      |    16388 |  2700014 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id                       | relation      |    16388 |   302490 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel2_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   333698 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel5_id_6dce956e264c19df_uniq | relation      |    16388 |  2576203 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_denorm_locs_id                                  | relation      |    16388 |  2725185 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_title_index                                     | relation      |    16388 |  2700114 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_name_129459df841fd9de_uniq                      | relation      |    16388 |   333668 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_location_id                                     | relation      |    16388 |   302517 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_end_date                                        | relation      |    16388 |   302483 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_pkey                                            | relation      |    16388 |   302308 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_name                                            | relation      |    16388 |   333705 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
                                                            | transactionid |          |          |       |       |            |      14771961 |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 core_location_loc_id                                       | relation      |    16388 |   302470 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel3_pkey                                            | relation      |    16388 |   302361 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_mymodel_id_5dcd946e263a391f_uniq           | relation      |    16388 |   302310 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
 core_mymodel_start_date                                      | relation      |    16388 |   302487 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/11758            | 2744 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel4_id                         | relation      |    16388 |   302491 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 core_mymodel_mymodel3s_pkey                                     | relation      |    16388 |   302312 |       |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/44               | 2241 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f
(91 rows)
```

As far as I can tell, the only client trying to access the id=123 row is the same client that's trying to UPDATE it. I'm also not sure why it's asking for locks for all those columns when all I fetched form the DB was a list of primary keys, and that query already finished. Also, when I have to kill the migration process when it hangs, a lot of these granted locks stick around. I've tried restarting my database but the migration still fails.

Also, `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid);` isn't stopping any of the backends, only restarting the DB seems to clear them out.

Comment: That last point is interesting - it suggests they're stuck doing work in something that doesn't `CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS`, like a library. If you're keen try attaching `gdb` and getting a backtrace of one of them. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it can be done since I'm using RDS.

Comment: I found this which is related to what Craig said: http://www.databaseproblem.com/893_12519729/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my DB, dropped the new field, readded it, then ran `VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE`. The UPDATE queries seem to be completing now, although a few of them will randomly take several orders of magnitude longer than the rest.